# Selector with argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

I have a method like this:

```
- (void)methodWithParameter:(id)parameter {
```

}

and I want to call it using an UIBarButtonItem

```
barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(methodWithParameter:)];
```

I want to specify the parameter but I can't use withObject: after action: because I get a warning:

> No -initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:withObject: method found

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. You cannot pass a parameter to an action. An action method will always have either:

- no arguments at all,
- one argument `(id)sender`,
- or two arguments `(id)sender` and `(UIEvent *)event`.

Comment: Thanks I think the only way of doing it is making another method without arguments which calls my methodWithParameter: method